# Guice instantiate different classes with different providers

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have two activities

```
public class GetActivity
{
    ChildClass childclass;

    @Inject
    public GetActivity(ChildClass childClass)
    {
        this.childClass = childclass;
    }
    String id = childClass.get(id);
    ....
}

public class SaveActivity
{
    ChildClass childclass;

    @Inject
    public SaveActivity(ChildClass childClass)
    {
        this.childClass = childclass;
    }
    childClass.save(id);
    ....
}
```

ChildClass is an interface with the following methods

```
public interface ChildClass
{
    String get(id);
    void save(id);
}
```

and its implemented as the following

```
public class ChildClassImpl implements ChildClass
{
    String storage;

    public ChildClassImpl(String storage)
    {
        this.storage =storage;
    }

    String get(Id)
    {
       someOtherObject.get(id, storage);
    }

    void save(id)
    {
       someOtherObject.save(id, storage);
    }
}
```

I wrote providers which will return the ChildClass method

```
public class ChildClassProvider1 implements Provider<ChildClass>
{
    @Override
    public ChildClass get()
    {
      ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass("hello");
    }
}

public class ChildClassProvider2 implements Provider<ChildClass>
{
    @Override
    public ChildClass get()
    {
      ChildClass childClass = new ChildClass("secondHello");
    }
}
```

I want to make sure that GetActivity and SaveActivity are initialzied with the provider ChildClassProvider1 but the other classes should use ChildClassProvider2. How to achieve this with guice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options, depending upon how hard you want to bake this requirement into your code.

Firstly, via a provides method In your module:

```
class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override protected void configure() {
    bind(ChildClass.class).toProvider(ChildClassProvider1.class);
  }

  @Provides SaveAction saveAction(ChildClassProvider2 provider) {
    return new SaveAction(provider.get());
  }
}
```

Secondly, via a binding annotation
Or, provide a binding annotation:

```
@BindingAnnotation @Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface YourAnnotation {}
```

Then:

```
// Ctor of SaveActivity.
@Inject
public SaveActivity(@YourAnnotation ChildClass childClass) { ... }

// In your module:
bind(ChildClass.class).annotatedWith(YourAnnotation.class)
    .toProvider(ChildClassProvider2.class);
```

The second option is "baking it in harder", because you have to put the binding annotation in the code; but it's a little less brittle (in the sense that you don't have to explicitly call the constructor), and feels "more guice-y".

The first option is keeping it a little looser, should you want to be able to configure things differently in certain circumstances.

Comment: I didn't understand your first method, you elaborate a bit more on that.